# Wiley journal "Wireless Communications and Mobile"

Tags: bibtex

I have a great problem with references presented to wiley journal. I downloaded `zotero` and start integration between it and microsoft word, I can't change my references style to the style "wcmc".

E.g this one of my references so how I convert it automatically to the required journal references?

> [1] “Internet engineer task force,” http://www.ietf.org/.
>
> [2]. J. Tripathi, J. de Oliveira, and J. Vasseur, “Performance Evaluation of Routing Protocol for Low Power and Lossy Networks (RPL),” IETF, Draft, January 2011.
>
> [3] A. Varga and R. Hornig, “An overview of the OMNeT++ simulation environment,” in Int Conf on Simulation Tools (ICST). ICST, 2008.
>
> [4] T. H. Clausen and U. Herberg, “Comparative Study of RPL-Enabled Optimized Broadcast in Wireless Sensor Networks
>   INRIA, Tech. Rep. 7296, 2010 
>   Multipoint-to-Point and Broadcast in RPL,” INRIA Tech. Rep. 7244, 2010. , ——, “

How can I use `zotero` to apply a new style over already exist refernces?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: thanks ruben .. but you have any idea about this issue

Comment: the required style already exist but how i can convert from my plain text references to the required style this is the question

Comment: Is this a question regarding `TeX/LaTeX/BibTex` or a question regarding `Microsoft Word` and `Zotero`? If it is regarding interaction between `bibtex`and `Word`, try [Bibtex4Word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/).

Comment: i need to convert my plain text references to bibtex file (.bib) to start converting them to my required style format

Comment: As it stands, this seems to boil down to 'How do I put this data into Zotero?': I don't see the requirement for BibTeX at all. Do I miss something?